# System.Windows.Application class leak

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I was looking for a leak in my application, when I encountered this problem. After stripping my application of all content this was the code that remained.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;

[STAThread]
int main(void)
{
    Application app;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        Window^ m = gcnew Window;
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment `Application app;` out, there is no leak, otherwise I run out of memory within a few seconds. Of course I don't need that many windows, but after adding a few hundred, which might occur, the private bytes keep increasing. I hope someone can tell me what's going on, since it is very important to me. Being careful with memory is mandatory for the application I'm building.

Comment: I love how people vote things down without saying why. Very educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was debugging, I decided not to open the window. I did this to isolate the leak. But it seems that not closing a window (even though it has never been opened) causes a leak.
[In this article](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.nl/2010/01/memory-leaks-with-wpf-windows.html) you can read that calling the `Window.Close` method fixes the problem and it did. The leak I was looking for wasn't where I thought it was.